# Typescript index types and length validation

Tags: typescript

Can somebody explain why in this example y.lenght is not an error?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200914#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAKDjgG0BrYSgLjgBnGFGQBzALoDaAbhYBfFi1CRYcGJTB4AYhAA2AEzRwAvMzaIDA4aKRi57cgFtg1keIfrNroe7ufsAAsEQyhgJAFdQzRCYlJyKjl5OSUVaHgNLTgooyhYkjIKSlMCIgKEmhy0ehSANwo4fmz9XPz4opLWdgBGASYgkIMwiKZ5ABoEKwAiACYpsedXAHJ0CAglsa8tASWAIwbM4CXFRRZ6qDgQTtPsMkF9YAA6PQgxAApKZ-CxGECAShYtyQ9z0Txe7xAXzsvz+QA

Comment: Because you're casting `y` as `: FolderDictionary`, which can have any string keys, including `lenght`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FolderDictionary` in your case is nothing but a `Record<string, Folder>` and in this record, key can be any string.

Hence you are able to call length on `FolderDictionary` and not just length but any string will not give compile error.

In second case `const x = {}`, you have not specified any type, hence ts infers it to specific type which is `{}` this.
And from the type, you can tell that this type does not have `length` key.

But if you explicitly add type like `const x: Record: <string, string> = {}`, then `y.length` will not give compile time error.

But note that, in both the cases, you will get `undefined` result, because that key does not exist.